# Константные объекты

Tags: c++, классы

```
 class A
 {
     const int x;
   public:
     A(const int& x = 0): x(x) {}
     ...
 };
 class B
 {
     int x;
   public:
     B(const int& x = 0): x(x) {}
     ...
 };
 int main()
 {
   A a;
   const B b;
 }
```

Объекты a и b эквивалентны?

Comment: Это объекты разных классов. О какой эквивалентности речь?

Comment: @alexolut при использовании

Comment: формально нет конечно

Comment: Дайте определение эквивалентности, тогда будет возможность ответить на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Лол. Ты че, явно нет

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Объекты a и b не являются эквивалентными, так как объект a - это неконстантный объект, а объект b - это константный объект.

Объект `a` вы можете передавать в функции, которые имеют своими параметрами неконстантные ссылки на класс `A`, в то время как объект `b` вы можете передавать в качестве аргументов функциям, которые имеют в качестве параметров константные ссылки.

Например, следующее объявление будет корректным для объекта `a`

```
A &ra = a;
```

в то время аналогичное объявление для объекта `b`

```
B &rb = b;
```

будет некорректным, так как объект `b` - это константный объект и для него правильно будет записать

```
const B &rb = b;
^^^^^
```

Или другой пример.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    const int x;
public:
    A(const int& x = 0): x(x) {}
    std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os )
    {
        return os << x;
    }        
 };

class B
{
    int x;
public:
    B(const int& x = 0): x(x) {}
    std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os )
    {
        return os << x;
    }        
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    const B b;

    a.out( std::cout ) << std::endl;    
    b.out( std::cout ) << std::endl;    // ошибка компиляции
}
```

В этой программе предложение

```
    b.out( std::cout ) << std::endl;    // ошибка компиляции
```

для объекта `b` не будет компилироваться, в то время как аналогичное предложение

```
    a.out( std::cout ) << std::endl;
```

для объекта `a` успешно скомпилируется и выполнится.

С точки зрения константности члена данных `x` обоих объектов, то оба эти члена данных для этих объявлений являются константными.

Answer (score 3):

Если речь о множестве действий, которые можно совершить над членом `x` в том или ином классе, то можно считать эквивалентными:

- доступ к `x` имеют только функции-члены соответствующих классов или
  друзья
- модификация `x` запрещена (в `a` константный член, в `b`
  константный весь объект)